# What is called on all visible cells when a new cell is inserted into a table view?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am creating a table view that allows users to comment on posts within my app. When a new comment is created, I am using the UITableView.insertRows(at:with:) method to add the new comment cell in its respective location.

The cells are adding to the table view correctly, but all other visible cells are having their subviews adjusted, i.e. their constraints are reset to the UITableViewCell's default constraints. Whenever I initially dequeue a cell, I call cell.layoutSubviews to set the constraints of the cells. This action is undone from the insertion of a new cell.

I've found that cellForRow(at:) is not called for the other visible cells whenever a new cell is inserted. I am curious what functions *are* called on the other visible functions whenever a new cell is inserted. This way, I can layout the respective, already existing cells' subviews to fix this issue. You'll see that when I "like" comments, the cells' subviews are appropriately laid out. This is because cell.layout subviews is called whenever the like button is pressed.

I am using UITableView.beginUpdates() and UITableView.endUpdates before and after the insertion respectively, and non-visible cells are, of course, not effected by the insert as their subviews are laid out when they are dequeued.

**In summary, I simply need to know what functions are being called on visible, already existing cells after a new cell is inserted into the table view.**

This like will navigate you to a video of my issue: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7MUr5C9Oj0c&feature=youtu.be

(Constraints code for Paul)

```
//The following is called on initialization
let viewsDict = ["contentView":contentView,"imageView":imageView,"textLabel":textLabel,"detailTextLabel":detailTextLabel,"timeLabel":timeLabel,"likesLabel":likesLabel,"likeButton":likeButton,"replyButton":replyButton] as [String:Any]

    //Horizontal constraints
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[imageView(35)]-[textLabel]-[likeButton(50)]-(-2)-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[imageView(35)]-[detailTextLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[imageView(35)]-[timeLabel]-[likesLabel]-[replyButton]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    //Vertical constriants
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[imageView(35)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-(-2)-[likeButton(50)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[textLabel]-[detailTextLabel]-[timeLabel]-8-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[textLabel]-[detailTextLabel]-[likesLabel]-8-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))

    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[textLabel]-[detailTextLabel]-[replyButton]-8-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
```

Within layoutSubviews, I check if the comment is a reply or deleted, and adjust accordingly. Replies will have an indentation, original posts will not. Deleted posts have no effect on constraints. The following is called with layoutSubviews:

```
//Check if constraints need to be adjusted
    if replyTo != nil && !isDeleted {
        //Is a reply, isn't deleted

        if indentImageView == nil {
            addIndentedConstraints()
        }

    } else if replyTo == nil && isDeleted {
        //Isn't a reply and is deleted

        if indentImageView != nil {
            removeIndentedConstraints()
        }

    } else if replyTo == nil && !isDeleted {
        //Isn't a reply and isn't deleted

        if indentImageView != nil {
            removeIndentedConstraints()
        }

    } else if replyTo != nil && isDeleted {
        //Is a reply, is deleted

        if indentImageView == nil {
            addIndentedConstraints()
        }

    }
```

And then the functions that either add indented constraints, or nonindented constraints:

```
func addIndentedConstraints() {
    indentImageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "indent")?.resize(targetSize: CGSize(width: 36, height: 18)))
    contentView.addSubview(indentImageView!)
    indentImageView!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    let viewsDict = ["contentView":contentView,"indentImageView":indentImageView,"imageView":imageView,"textLabel":textLabel,"detailTextLabel":detailTextLabel,"timeLabel":timeLabel,"likesLabel":likesLabel,"likeButton":likeButton,"replyButton":replyButton,] as [String:Any]

    let indentedConstraints1 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-67.5-[imageView(35)]-[textLabel]-[likeButton(50)]-(-2)-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)
    indentedConstraints1.giveAllConstraints(identifier: "indentedConstraint")
    contentView.addConstraints(indentedConstraints1)

    let indentedConstraints2 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-25.5-[indentImageView(36)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)
    indentedConstraints2.giveAllConstraints(identifier: "indentedConstraint")
    contentView.addConstraints(indentedConstraints2)

    let indentedConstraints3 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[indentImageView(18)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)
    indentedConstraints3.giveAllConstraints(identifier: "indentedConstraint")
    contentView.addConstraints(indentedConstraints3)

    let indentedConstraints4 = NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-[imageView(35)]", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict)
    indentedConstraints4.giveAllConstraints(identifier: "indentedConstraint")
    contentView.addConstraints(indentedConstraints4)
}

func removeIndentedConstraints() {
    indentImageView!.removeFromSuperview()
    indentImageView = nil

    //Loop through all of our contentview's constraints and check if the constraint is an indentedConstraint. Remove this constraint if it is
    for constraint in contentView.constraints {
        if constraint.identifier == "indentedConstraint" {
            contentView.removeConstraint(constraint)
        }
    }
    let viewsDict = ["contentView":contentView,"imageView":imageView,"textLabel":textLabel,"detailTextLabel":detailTextLabel,"timeLabel":timeLabel,"likesLabel":likesLabel,"likeButton":likeButton,"replyButton":replyButton,] as [String:Any]
    contentView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-[imageView(35)]-[textLabel]-|", options: NSLayoutConstraint.FormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: viewsDict))
}
```

[NSLayoutConstraint].giveAllConstraints(identifier:) naturally gives all elements in a NSLayoutConstraint array the same identifier. This way, I can loop through and check whether a constraint is an indentation constraint, and then only remove the ones that are if need be.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614896-visiblecells . This will give you all visible cells.   And willDisplayCell will be called for new cell created https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdelegate/1614883-tableview

Comment: @Digs The willDisplayCell method only effects the cell being inserted, and I tried looping through visible cells and calling cell.layoutSubviews() after the insertion, but my problem persists.

I know that some function on the visible cells is being called as their subviews are adjusting after the insertion. I just need to find and edit that function.

Comment: You are doing right .. Insertion and deletion should be called between begin and endUpdate. Between this space is where you want to make changes ...  CellForRowAt is called when you make reload  . Try without calling layoutSubview

Comment: Can you show the code you use to adjust the constraints?  What is your row height set to in the tableview (I assume you are adjusting the cell height to fit the content)?  When the cell is inserted an autolayout pass is performed. It sounds like the cell constraints and/or row height aren't set correctly.

Comment: @Paulw11 I actually figured it out. It was pretty dumb, but as I wanted cellForRow at: to be called after the insertion on all visible cells, I simply had to call tableView.reloadRows after my insertion and before tableView.endUpdates(). Posting code in a second here.

Comment: It should not be necessary to reload the rows after inserting one.

Comment: @Paulw11 I agree, but all of my visible cells were having their constraints changed after the insertion. Reloading them was the only way I found I could recall layoutSubviews following the insertion. I could still post the code to my CommentCell constraints if you'd like (I was using visual formatting).

Comment: I would like to see the code (although visual formatting is discouraged in favour of layout anchors these days; it is less error prone and tends to be easier to read). Constraints aren't changed by the layout process

Comment: @Paulw11 I just added the code. I am new to adding constraints to UITableViewCells programmatically; I'm used to interface builder. Let me know if there is anything else you'd like to see. I'll also post a video of the final result now that it's working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191338/discussion-between-paulw11-and-david-chopin).

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm not sure I have enough reputation to initiate a chat. Regardless, here is a video of it working a little bit better now. Still needs work, but better than before.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ONAhG2GhEEs

Comment: You have enough rep or it won’t show the option. I have to go for about 30 mins though

Comment: @Paulw11 I'm just not seeing the option to initiate a conversation then I guess. Regardless, thanks for your help man. Feel free to reach out if you want to talk more later.

Comment: @Paulw11 avoid calling reloadData since its a expensive call and its reloads every cell

Comment: @Digs I'm calling reloadRows (only the visible cells) not reloadData.

Comment: You only need 20 rep to participate in chat.  You don't need to initiate the chat.  Simply click on the link where it says [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191338/discussion-between-paulw11-and-david-chopin)

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up finding was that, cellForRow at: is only called on the cells being inserted when tableView.insertRows is called. Calling tableView.reloadRows before tableView.endUpdates and passing the index paths of all visible cells caused all of my visible cells to reload and, naturally, layout their subviews.

Initial code:

```
self!.tableView.beginUpdates()
self!.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
self!.tableView.endUpdates()
```

Code that works:

```
self!.tableView.beginUpdates()
self!.tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .none)
self!.tableView.reloadRows(at: self!.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with: .none)
self!.tableView.endUpdates()
```